# Rdlc to excel, format number is lost

Tags: excel, rdlc

When I export from RDLC to excel file, I'm group data to many sheet, the sheets in the beginning is ok, number is formatted correctly, but keeping move on, the format is ignored, it is not applied anymore.
How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from library NPOI. It's always create new style for each cell, it cached but in limited, we need write extra code to make it work when merge multiple files.